# count how many times a record appears in a pandas dataframe and create a new feature with this counter

Tags: python, pandas

I have this two dataframes dt_t and dt_u. I want to be able to count how many times a record in the text feature appears and I want to create a new feature in df_u where I associate to each id the counter. So id_u = 1 and id_u = 2 both will have counter = 3 since hello appears 3 times in df_t and both published a post with "hello" in the text.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_t = pd.DataFrame({'id_t': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 'id_u': [1, 1, 3, 2, 2], 'text': ["hello", "hello", "friend", "hello", "my"]})

print(df_t)

df_u = pd.DataFrame({'id_u': [1, 2, 3]})

print()
print(df_u)

df_u_new = pd.DataFrame({'id_u': [1, 2, 3], 'counter': [3, 3, 1]})

print()  
print(df_u_new)
```

The code I wrote for the moment is this, but this is very slow and also I have a very huge dataset so it is impossible to do.

```
user_counter_dict = {}
tmp = dict(df_t["text"].value_counts())

# to speedup the process we set as index the text column
df_t.set_index(["text"], inplace=True)
for i, (k, v) in enumerate(tmp.items()):
    row = (k, v)
    text = row[0]
    counter = row[1]
    
    #this is slow and take much of the time
    uniques_id = df_.loc[tweet]["id_u"].unique()
    
    for elem in uniques_id:
      value = user_counter_dict.setdefault(str(elem), counter)
      if value < counter:
        user_counter_dict[str(elem)] = counter
    # and now I will put the date on the dict on a new column in df_u
```

Is there a very fast way to compute this?

Comment: *since hello appears 3 times in df_t and both published a post with "hello" in the text.*...I don't see "hello" appear against either 1 or 2. Its not clear why the counter will be 3, 3, 1 for those ids from your description.

Comment: @SomeDude so I want to compute how many times the text "hello" appears in the datasets. Then I want to retrieve every id_u that posted "hello" and add this counter on df_u for each id_u

Comment: @JayJona have id_u 2 correspond to 3, 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
df_u_new = df_t.assign(counter=df_t["text"].map(df_t["text"].value_counts()))[
    ["id_u", "counter"]
].groupby("id_u", as_index=False).max()
```

Get the `value_counts` of `text` and groupby `id_u` and get the maximum value which is what you were trying to get IIUC.

```
print(df_u_new)

   id_u  counter
0     1        3
1     2        3
2     3        1
```

Comment: thank you this is the easiest and fastest way